# run realize start for a Go program, outputs exec: not started

Tags: configuration

when I run `realize start` for a Go program, I got this error result

```
[14:55:13][V2-USER-API.YUMMY.ID] : Watching 159 file/s 118 folder/s
[14:55:13][V2-USER-API.YUMMY.ID] : Install started
[14:55:13][V2-USER-API.YUMMY.ID] : Install 
 exec: not started
```

I have set up my file .realize.yaml, like this

```
settings:
  legacy:
    force: false
    interval: 0s
schema:
- name: v2-user-api.yummy.id
  path: ./cmd/server
  commands:
    run:
      status: true
  watcher:
    extensions:
    - go
    paths:
    - ../../
    ignored_paths:
    - .git
    - .realize
    - vendor
```

but I got error after run `realize start`

Comment: My "mad psychic debugging skillz" suggest you're talking about <https://github.com/oxequa/realize>, are you? If yes, this question cannot be tagged `go` because it has nothing to do with _programming_ in Go. Please consider asking it on superuser.com or—better—start [here](https://github.com/oxequa/realize#support-and-suggestions).

Comment: …and while we're at it, [the language is called Go](https://golang.org/doc/faq#go_or_golang).

Answer (score 1):

This command work for me

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

export GO111MODULE=off

cd ~/
go get github.com/oxequa/realize
cd /go/src/github.com/oxequa/realize && \
  git fetch && \
  git checkout v2.0.2 && \
  go get github.com/oxequa/realize

RV=$(realize --version)
echo "Realize installed @: $RV"

export GO111MODULE=on
```

use realize version v2.0.2